# What is New Year in North India called?

Tags: culture, festivals, calendar, navrathri

I did try to read online but some pages say Phalgun Poornima while others say Chaitra Shukla Pratipada. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Chaitra Shukla pratipada is the new year for all over India (except sometimes business communities in Gujarat celebrate Diwali as new year).